# Systemd service (calling sh script as services) - how to get updated status

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, startup

I have the following working systemctl `systemd` startup script that automatically starts on reboot perfectly (other dbdeployer dependency starting too).

Its a `.sh script` where I created a few different 'states', basically for the services called.

(One startup script uses *docker-compose* project, while the other is for a *dbdeployer mysql instance*)

#### Systemd service unit for *docker-compose containers*:

```
[Unit]
Description=Magento 2.3.5 Docker-Compose Containers
After=dbdeployer-mysql-5-731-in-1.service
Requires=docker.service dbdeployer-mysql-5-731-in-1.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/_systemd.startups_/glolighting/magento/2_35/docker-compose.mag2.35.env.file
#Environment=FILE_SCRIPT=/var/www/docker/_systemd.startups_/magento/2_35/dc-glo-mag235.sh
#PassEnvironment=$DCFOLDER
Type=simple
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
RestartSec=4s
RemainAfterExit=yes
#WorkingDirectory=${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER}
ExecStartPre=mkdir -p ${LOGFOLDER}
ExecStartPre=echo ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER}
ExecStartPre=echo Starting Docker-compose service for ${DESCRIPTION}...
ExecStartPre=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 1
ExecStart=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 2
ExecStartPost=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 1
ExecStop=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 3
ExecStopPost=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### The script being called by `systemd`:

```
____truncated for relevance___
# Continue on success
if [ $arguments_correct -eq 1 ]; then
   cd $PATH_DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_FILE

   if [ $OPTION -eq 1 ]; then
         echo "$LINE"
         echo ""
         $(which docker-compose) ps
         echo ""
         echo "$LINE"
   elif [ $OPTION -eq 2 ]; then
         $(which docker-compose) start
   elif [ $OPTION -eq 3 ]; then
         $(which docker-compose) stop
   fi
   exit 0
fi
```

I was hoping `ExecStartPost=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 1` will supply me with the correct output, (in other words `$(which docker-compose) ps`, but there is a delay - docker containers can take from ~3-10 seconds.  So, since this status does not update (requery) everytime you call the `status` command, I only see the output when the original `ExecStartPost` occurred.

To summarize: once I do `systemctl status docker-compose-mag235.service`, I will get output to say that some docker-containers are still `exit/starting` state.

### Question

Is there any way to use `systemctl status docker-compose-mage235.service` (or equivalent `systemctl` command) that will be able to give me an **updated status**.  _In other words: The status of `$(which docker-compose) ps` at the moment I ran this new systemctl command.

(Before creating these startup systemd services, I always assumed that the state is 're-queried' for every call, but then I realized it's just taking the last output from logfiles (most likely `syslog`)).

### NOTE:

Calling `/location/of/project/file/of/docker-compose.yml` is possible, but I would rather just want to house different `systemd services` that I can query based on Docker Compose project, in other words I have multiple folders for different DC projects.  And then I would need to create aliases, but before I do that I would know if `systemd` can help me.

Comment: There is no point in running docker-compose as `$(which docker-compose)`.  Either it's in the PATH, so it can be run as just `docker-compose`, or it's not in the PATH and `which` won't find it.

Comment: Also, quote your variables whenever you use them.    In your code snippet above, all of the following should be double-quoted, not just `"$LINE"`: `$arguments_correct`, `$PATH_DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_FILE`, and `$OPTION`

Comment: Finally, instead of having several ExecStartPre lines AND an ExecStart script, just have one script that does everything in the ExecStartPre and ExecStart lines.    Probably ExecStartStop too.   Same for ExecStop* entries too, they should be in their own script (a different script to ExecStart - or the same script called with different arguments).

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding quotes, I realized that I do not always do that in my scripts.  Its something I just need to get used to regarding scripts - examples most of the time show unquoted.  `$(which docker-compose)` : makes sense, it is in the PATH.  I was testing out `ExecStart*` behaviour, and it was just my misunderstanding (and my question maybe also showing that) that initially I thought _status_ can be requeried via one of the Pre/Post*  commands.  The end plan is to combine everything into one script once everything worked.

Comment: The Exec*Pre and Exec*Post commands can't do what you want.  They're run once, before (Pre) or after (Post) a service is started or stopped.   BTW, in case it's not obvious, i made a typo with `ExecStartStop` in my comment above.  That should be `ExecStartPost`.

Comment: Yes I noticed that the commands were different from my original. I assumed you meant `ExecStartPost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible unless you can somehow make `docker-compose` send extra info to systemd's journal.

`systemctl status` shows the status of the service, and the most recent journal entries for the service.

You can view more log entries by running `journalctl -b0 -p 0..7 -u docker-compose`.  That will give you all docker-compose journal log entries since the last reboot.

Comment: A pity, I will see if I can 'delay' the script completion, such that `ExecStartPost` can execute a bit later in time (or just combine everything into `ExecStart` as you suggest.

Comment: There's no reason why your ExecStartPost script can't keep repeatedly checking if everything's started OK (with a second or 2 or more sleep between each check) before it finishes.   Whether you can output more status info to the journal log - I don't know....maybe print to STDERR

Comment: That's what I will try. Thanks for your assistance and advice!

Comment: @CvRChameleon if you have an answer that works for you, you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to my answer.   and if you like your answer better than mine, then go right ahead and change your accepted answer (i won't be offended :-)

Comment: No, your answer answered my question:  It is not directly possible using only systemd itself, but a 'hacky way' using the script that gets called via `ExecStartPost`, and `ExecStopPost`.  I thought just giving more information as to your answer (which is correctly answering my question) would be useful.  Your answer will remain accepted!
TLDR: other people looking for a what to do: let your script `loop until some expected result is found in your loop or sleep before calling the actual status code` (for me I needed to delay `docker-compose ps`)

Comment: I think you should post that as an answer.  You put in the work to figure it out. I just posted "nope, can't do it".    An answer is whatever works, even if it's "you can't do it how you want, but here's how you can".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @cas for pointing out that it is not possible to get an 'updated status' from `systemd` directly.  He pointed me and advised:

> There's no reason why your ExecStartPost script can't keep repeatedly checking if everything's started OK (with a second or 2 or more sleep between each check) before it finishes. Whether you can output more status info to the journal log - I don't know....maybe print to STDERR

This then made me realize that I could potentially just delay the script, as opposed to my original objective: getting status directly from `systemd 'somestatuscommand-that-queries'`.

In my case my script could be adapted slightly by giving an extra input argument **only when `ExecStartPost` and `ExecStopPost` executes**.

Extra input arguments only for these commands:

```
ExecStartPost=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 1 **4**
ExecStopPost=bash ${SERVICE_FILE_SCRIPT} ${DC_PROJECT_FOLDER} 1 **4**
```

```
____truncated for relevance___
# Continue on success
if [ $arguments_correct -eq 1 ]; then
   cd $PATH_DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_FILE

   if [ $OPTION -eq 1 ]; then
      if [ $sleep_correct -eq 1]; then
         # Sleep here when requested (and sleep input verified above)
         sleep $SLEEP
      fi
      #Now docker-compose ps has been given enough time to query after containers were started/stopped.
         echo "$LINE"
         echo ""
         $(which docker-compose) ps
         echo ""
         echo "$LINE"
   elif [ $OPTION -eq 2 ]; then
         $(which docker-compose) start
   elif [ $OPTION -eq 3 ]; then
         $(which docker-compose) stop
   fi
   exit 0
fi
```

Not sure why `systemd` was not given this type of capability - I assume some important design decisions that I won't understand right now, but this means extra work for each and every 'script type `systemd` unit'.

Comment: +1. but you still need to [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).  and stop using that pointless `$(which docker-compose)`.

Comment: I have done that in my final script early this morning, just didn't apply it on my answer yet.  Thanks for +1, and really helpful advice!